# function in Julia equivalent to matlabfunction()?

Tags: matlab, julia

I need a function equivalent to `matlabfunction()` of matlab, does anyone know if there is or how to do?

Function documentation in MatLab:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/matlabfunction.html

I'm doing a translation of MatLab for Julia . This part that I am having difficulties:

```
syms x
dados = inputdlg({'P(x): ', 'Q(x): ', 'R(x): ', 'N: '},'Dados');
P = matlabFunction(sym(dados{1}),'vars',x,'file','px');
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: As far as I know, core Julia doesn't do symbolic math. Are you using something like SymPy with it? Be specific.

Comment: I tried using the SymPy, but still not getting success, thanks for your help.

Comment: @ Willian : it is clear you are not quite sure what you're asking. `matlabFunction` is a function that converts a _symbolic_ expression to an equivalent _anonymous function handle_. The equivalent to a function handle in julia is an anonymous function / lambda. Julia has a few packages (listed in pkg.julialang.org) that supposedly deal with symbolic maths, but it doesn't seem you're using any of them, or that you're interested in the symbolic part to begin with. So what is it you're trying to do exactly? Are you just trying to get the user to provide the definition of a function as text input?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand what `matlabfunction` is, you don't need it in Julia.

Here is a MATLAB example:

```
syms x y
r = sqrt(x^2 + y^2);
ht = matlabFunction(sin(r)/r)
```

and here is the same in Julia:

```
julia> ht = (x,y) -> (r=sqrt(x^2 + y^2); sin(r)/r)
(anonymous function)

julia> ht(1,1)
0.6984559986366083
```

It looks like `matlabfunction` does some other things too, but you'd need to give a more concrete question for me to tackle that.

EDIT: This answer addressed question in its original form - an edit has changed it but hasn't added much clarification.